# How can I be notified whenever the printer is used? Dbus? Something else?

Tags: 12.04, printing, dbus

I need to know in my application if the printer is being used by some other application.

Is there some way I can get notified? Via dbus perhaps, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

you need [system-config-printer-applet](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man1/system-config-printer-applet.1.html).

> system-config-printer-applet is a print job manager for CUPS. Normally
>          it will display a printer icon in the notification area, greyed out
>          when there are no print jobs for the current user. Clicking on the icon
>          displays a simple print job manager for cancelling or reprinting jobs.

For package : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/system-config-printer-gnome

Comment: I think he actually means something that can be used in his application's code to query dbus, like `python-dbus`.

Comment: I mention that because " Is there some way I can get notified?"

Comment: That's correct Mik.